# How can I update using information from the main query in a subquery?

Tags: sql, mysql, subquery

I handle articles on a multi-language site, with the possibility for the users to update the content. I use a MySQL database.

Table `articles`: `id`

Table `article_contents`: `id` `article_id` (FK) `content` `lang` `version`

If the new content is still a draft, `version` is `null`. As soon as the draft is validated by a moderator, it becomes a definitive version and takes the next available `version` for the given `article_id` and the given `lang`.

```sql
UPDATE article_contents
SET version=(
    SELECT MAX(version)
    FROM article_contents
    WHERE article_id=SAME_AS_THE_ONE_IN_THE_MAIN_QUERY
    AND lang=SAME_AS_THE_ONE_IN_THE_MAIN_QUERY
) + 1
WHERE id=:id;
```

By what can I replace `SAME_AS_THE_ONE_IN_THE_MAIN_QUERY`, or is there a cleaner way to do it?

Answer (score 2):

Use a *correlated subquery*, i.e. let it reference the update table:

```
update article_contents ac
set version = coalesce((select max(version)
                        from article_contents
                        where article_id = ac.article_id
                          and lang = ac.lang), 0) + 1
where id = :id;
```

Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/IkH8jGmy

Answer (score 1):

If you are fine with using variables, try smt like this (T-SQL):

```sql
begin
 declare @v_test NVARCHAR(MAX)
 declare @v_lang NVARCHAR(MAX)

-- IDK where id/lang comes from, so I'm just setting them like this
 set @v_test = 'VC000033'
 set @v_lang = 'eng'

    update [your table]
    set [your column] = (
        select max([your column]) + 1
        from [your table]
        where No_ = @v_test
        and lang = @v_lang)
    where No_ = @v_test
end
```

Depending on the operations you are performing,
this might not be the best solution performance wise.
For that you might wanna try [CTE](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)

Comment: Product specific answer to a question with no dbms specified. At least let OP and other readers know which dbms this is for.

Comment: BTW, note that tables have _columns_, not fields.

Answer (score 1):

```
   UPDATE ac  
   SET version=(
        SELECT TOP 1 ISNULL(version,0)
        FROM article_contents ac2
        WHERE ac2.article_id  = ac.article_id 
            AND ac2.lang = ac.lang
        ORDER BY 1 desc
    ) + 1
    FROM article_contents ac
    WHERE id=@id;
```

Comment: Note _next available version for the given article_id and the given lang_.

Comment: Product specific answer to a question with no dbms specified. At least let OP and other readers know which dbms this is for.

Comment: Please don't insert "EDIT"s/"UPDATE"s/etc, just make your post the best presentation as of edit time. [When is "EDIT"/"UPDATE" appropriate in a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/127639/266284) Please avoid social & meta commentary in posts. Please delete & flag obsolete comments. [ask] [Help] [meta] [meta.se]

Answer (score 0):

See example

```
UPDATE article_contents ac
   ,(
    SELECT article_id,lang,MAX(version) maxversion
    FROM article_contents
    group by article_id,lang
   ) t
  SET version= coalesce(t.maxversion,0)+ 1
WHERE ac.article_id=t.article_id and ac.lang=t.lang
  and ac.id=@id;
```

In your query, I think, main problem is `You can't specify target table 'article_contents' for update in FROM clause`

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/NotEXnR0)